# domain masking with file downloading

Tags: php

i have a domain abc.com host in server 1 and def.com host in server 2.

file is host at domain def.com in server 2. i want hide def.com domain by masking using abc.com. Example: when i open link abc.com with token (abc.com?token=8888), if token found it will choose file from domain def.com in server 2. Meaning when i download file, it will get the file from domain def.com in server 2 by showing it download from domain abc.com.

1. can i know it is possible to do like that? using technic url masking right?
2. also when downloading, it will use bandwidth from domain abc.com from server 1 or it will use bandwidth from domain def.com from server 2?

Answer (score 1):

> can i know it is possible to do like that? using technic url masking right?

This is generally done by configuring your HTTP server to act as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

> also when downloading, it will use bandwidth from domain abc.com from server 1 or it will use bandwidth from domain def.com from server 2?

Both.

In order for the client to download the file from server 1 without ever knowing about server 2 the file has to be sent from server 1 to the client.

Transferring the file from server 1 to the client will use server 1's bandwidth.

However, server 1 needs to access the file in the first place. Since you are talking about different servers (and not different domains on the same server) then the file has to be transferred over the network from server 2. This will use server 1's **and** server 2's bandwidth.

i.e. for a 1MB file you are talking:

- 1 MB transfer from server 2
- 1 MB transfer to server 1
- 1 MB transfer from server 1
- 1 MB transfer to the client

Assuming you don't care about the client's bandwidth, that's 3 MB of your bandwidth.

You can reduce that for subsequent requests for the same file by caching the data on server 1.

Comment: for caching data on server 1, it needs use storage on server 1 right?

Comment: Yes, of course.